# JSF Converter. El método getAsObject() recibe string vacio en el parámetro value

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación JSF en la que utilizo un control `<p:autoComplete.../>` sobre el que tengo definido un converter. A continuación muestro el bloque de código citado:

```
<h:outputText                               
    style="margin-left: 10px;"
    value="Operario "/>
<p:autoComplete
    size="10"
    forceSelection="true"
    style="margin-left: 10px;"
    converter="#{operarioConverter}"
    value="#{monitorizadorCentroControlador.calidadEditarControlesBean.operarioSeleccionado}"
    var="operario"
    completeMethod="#{monitorizadorCentroControlador.calidadEditarControlesBean.autocompletarOperario}"
    itemLabel="#{operario.codigo}" itemValue="#{operario}">
        <p:ajax
            event="itemSelect"
            update="operarioControlesCalidadNombre"/>
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{operario.codigo}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{operario.nombre}"/>
        </p:column>
</p:autoComplete>
```

La implementación del converter es la siguiente:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "operarioConverter")
@SessionScoped
@FacesConverter(forClass = OperarioDTO.class)
public class OperarioConverter implements Converter, Serializable {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        System.out.println("OperarioConverter.getAsObject: " + value);
        long id = -1;
        try{
            id = Long.parseLong(value);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            return null;
        }
        Transaction t = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
        try{
            Operario e = new OperarioServiceImpl().find(id);
            OperarioDTO operarioDTO = OperarioMapper.INSTANCE.operarioToOperarioDTO(e);
            t.commit();
            return operarioDTO;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            t.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        System.out.println("OperarioConverter.getAsString: " + value);
        if (value instanceof Operario){
            return ((OperarioDTO)value).getId().toString();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

El problema es que cuando se realiza la llamada al método `getAsObject(...)`, el parámetro `value` del mismo es una cadena vacía.

Comment: Comprueba que el método getAsString no esté devolviendo null.

Comment: Efectivamente, no había comprobado correctamente el funcionamiento de getAsString().

Comment: ¿Ya está resuelto el problema?

Comment: Si ya está resuelto. El problema residía en que getAsString devolvía null.

Answer (score 2):

Te recomiendo no realizar transacciones directas a la base de datos cada vez que se ejecute el método getAsObject(), ya que no es recomendable según la documentación y la mayoría de los catálogos pueden manejarse en un Bean con alcance de Aplicación. Podrías implementar un catálogo dinámico dentro del objeto del convertidor. Por ejemplo:

```
public class CampoPlantillaConverter implements Converter{
List<CampoPlantilla> campos;

public CampoPlantillaConverter()
{
    super();

}

public CampoPlantillaConverter(List<CampoPlantilla> campos)
{
    this.campos = campos;

}

@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, String string)
{

    for (CampoPlantilla cam : this.campos)
    {
        if (("" + cam.hashCode()).equalsIgnoreCase(string))
        {
            return cam;
        }
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object o)
{
    if (o != null)
    {
        return "" + o.hashCode();
    }

    return null;

}

public List<CampoPlantilla> getCampos()
{
    return campos;
}

public void setCampos(List<CampoPlantilla> campos)
{
    this.campos = campos;
}}
```

De esta forma, puedes utilizar el convertidor como un objeto dentro del Bean y llenar el catálogo dinámicamente.
La forma de implementarlo la puedes encontrar aquí:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uyk0UPc8oBU

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

No sé si tiene que ver que has utilizado las anotaciones `@ManagedBean` y `@SessionScoped`. Yo hago uso de un convertidor común para todas mis entidades. Te lo dejo por si lo desean implementar en tu proyecto:

```
/**
 * Converter para entidades JPA. Baseia-se nas anotações @Id e @EmbeddedId para
 * identificar o atributo que representa a identidade da entidade. Capaz de
 * detectar as anotações nas classes superiores.
 *
 * @author Flávio Henrique
 * @version 1.0.3
 * @since 05/10/2010
 */
@FacesConverter("entityConverter")
public class EntityConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext ctx, UIComponent component, String value) {
        if (value != null) {
            return component.getAttributes().get(value);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext ctx, UIComponent component, Object obj) {
        if (obj != null && !"".equals(obj)) {
            String id;
            try {
                id = this.getId(getClazz(ctx, component), obj);
                if (id == null) {
                    id = "";
                }
                id = id.trim();
                component.getAttributes().put(id, getClazz(ctx, component).cast(obj));
                return id;
            } catch (SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); // seu log aqui
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Obtém, via expression language, a classe do objeto.
     *
     * @param FacesContext facesContext
     * @param UICompoment compoment
     * @return Class<?>
     */
    private Class<?> getClazz(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component) {
        return component.getValueExpression("value").getType(facesContext.getELContext());
    }

    /**
     * Retorna a representação em String do retorno do método anotado com @Id ou
     *
     * @param obj
     * @throws java.lang.NoSuchFieldException
     * @throws java.lang.IllegalAccessException
     * @EmbeddedId do objeto.
     * @param clazz<?> clazz
     * @return String
     */
    public String getId(Class<?> clazz, Object obj) throws SecurityException, NoSuchFieldException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {

        List<Class<?>> hierarquiaDeClasses = this.getHierarquiaDeClasses(clazz);

        for (Class<?> classeDaHierarquia : hierarquiaDeClasses) {
            for (Field field : classeDaHierarquia.getDeclaredFields()) {
                if ((field.getAnnotation(Id.class)) != null || field.getAnnotation(EmbeddedId.class) != null) {
                    Field privateField = classeDaHierarquia.getDeclaredField(field.getName());
                    privateField.setAccessible(true);
                    if (privateField.get(clazz.cast(obj)) != null) {
                        return (String) field.getType().cast(privateField.get(clazz.cast(obj))).toString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Retorna uma lista com a hierarquia de classes, sem considerar a classe
     * Object.class
     *
     * @param clazz
     *
     * @return List<Class<?>> clazz
     */
    public List<Class<?>> getHierarquiaDeClasses(Class<?> clazz) {

        List<Class<?>> hierarquiaDeClasses = new ArrayList<>();
        Class<?> classeNaHierarquia = clazz;
        while (classeNaHierarquia != Object.class) {
            hierarquiaDeClasses.add(classeNaHierarquia);
            classeNaHierarquia = classeNaHierarquia.getSuperclass();

        }
        return hierarquiaDeClasses;
    }
}
```

Y lo llamas de esta forma en el componente que lo necesite:

```
converter="entityConverter"
```

Como puedes ver, no es de mi autoría, por lo que coloco los créditos. Este convertidor me funciona para todas las entidades de mi proyecto, solo en casos especiales me toca hacer uso de otro.